# Are patients with hidradenitis suppurativa overweight due to the disease itself?

Tags: statistics, overweight, emotional-eating

After reading about 5 journals on the disease, I noticed they all mention that HS sufferers are usually overweight. They also say that losing weight could mitigate the effects of the disease. I have not found any experimental data recording the condition before and after weight loss for a particular group, so my understanding is that the conclusion was drawn from the fact that many sufferers are overweight.

My question is how can this conclusion be empirically deduced from the observation that many HS sufferers are overweight? Could it not be that they are overweight due to the discomfort of exercise due to the condition? Or even due to eating because they're depressed (chronic depression is a known co-morbidity)

Answer (score -1):

The best theory relating the two things I've seen is that HS is caused by high GI, Carb or dairy diet which also can cause obesity.

The sores form mostly where there's friction of skin and being overweight can exacerbate that.

Comment: Hi! Post here usually have links to support content. Adding them would help follow site guidelines. Consult the Help Center or ask here for any other questions. Thank you!